# Is light a single wave when we refer to frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, frequency

When we say that light oscillates $n$ times (frequency) in a second do we mean that the same electromagnetic field travelling through space oscillates $n$ time's? As i have seen diagrams suggesting many waves at a second but I need to know is it the same wave just repeating $n$ times a second or are they multiple waves.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Light is made of individual photons. A light wave Is billions of individual coherent and oscillating photons, radiating from a common source. You cannot even begin to explain what a wave is physically without introducing photons. It’s impossible. Your question only begins to touch on this problem.

Comment: wait. so in this gif https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4c/Electromagneticwave3D.gif/220px-Electromagneticwave3D.gif
it shoes an oscillating field at every point of space. is it the same em field moving through space or after each oscillation it's a new field and a new photon?

Comment: @BhoumikSahoo If you can Forget the field and forget the wave you can visualize the gif as a stream of individual photons. In this case the photons are coherent with all of them originating at the same point, traveling the same exact direction and oscillating at the same frequency. Each one is the same individual photon oscillating from beginning to end, and none of them restart new.

Answer (score 1):

I was just copying this gif

[image: em]

> [Electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Properties) can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This 3D animation shows a plane linearly polarized wave propagating from left to right. The electric and magnetic fields in such a wave are in-phase with each other, reaching minima and maxima together.

Note the "plane linearly polarized" in this model.

So the *classical theory of electrodynamics* has electric and magnetic fields in a sinusoidal way where the [Poynting vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwv.html) models the energy transferred by the wave. At a point in space, as the gif shows the electric and magnetic fields change according to a sine and cosine dependence as the energy moves in the ray direction.

The classical theory is successful in describing the behavior of light.

> I need to know is it the same wave just repeating n times a second or are they multiple waves.

It depends on the geometry if one could call it one wave or multiple. If there are many parallel rays of polarized light as in the gif it could be labeled "one wave". If it is composed of incoherent sources and un-polarized one cannot call it one wave, similar to the intuition of water waves . The frequency is what determines the color whether the light is coherent or not.

At the quantum mechanical level it can be shown mathematically that the classical wave is built up by a great number of photons , but it needs quantum field theory background to understand.